# Angular directive how to set context variable generic type?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm facing the same issue from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991166/angular-structural-directive-context-template-type-checking), and since there's no answer there, I will try to ask.

I have created a directive `ngStream` that will subscribe to an observable, and automatic unsubscribe once the component is destroyed, I know the `async` pipe exists, but it requires an array like: `Observable<T[]>`, so I decided to create this directive that allows to subscribe into a normal `Observable<T>` and I don't need to emit an array of a single element, here is what I have, and it's working:

```
export class NgStreamDirective implements OnDestroy {
    @Input('ngStreamOf') set values(obs: Observable<any>) {
        this.subscription = obs.subscribe((o) => {
            this.value = o;

            if (this.embeddedRef === undefined) {
                this.embeddedRef = this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._template, { "\$implicit": this.value });
            } else {
                this.embeddedRef.context.$implicit = this.value;
                this.embeddedRef.detectChanges();
            }
        });
    }

    private subscription: Subscription;
    private value: any;

    private embeddedRef: EmbeddedViewRef<any>;

    constructor(
        private _template: TemplateRef<any>,
        private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) {}

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

I plan to improve this code, but right now I just need to make it work the right way, and it is working, the only problem is that I can't define a generic type for my `value`, for example:

```
*ngFor="let i of [0, 1, 2...]"
```

In this case the variable `i` will be a `number` type, if I change the type of the list the variable will also change it's type, as you probably know.

In my case:

```
observable$: Observable<String>
*ngStream="let stream of observable$"
```

The variable stream it's an `any` type and I can't figure out a way of setting the return type, I've also seen this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28731) that seems to have to same problem and no solution.

Comment: No, the async Pipe does not require an array. Quote: "I know the async pipe exists, but it requires an array like: Observable<T[]>"

Comment: @Crazybutch My mistake, any way ngFor requires an iterable, I'll get an error from angular if I don't emit an Observable of array, this is the error `Cannot find a differ supporting object '...' of type 'object'`

Comment: You could use <ng-container *ngIf="yourVariable$ | async as data">{{data.firstName}}</ng-container> if you want to use all the benefits of the async Pipe without having an iterable. Unfortunately I can't help with the type Problem, maybe you just have a look at how the Angular Team solved it: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts